# Locking a custom dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, locking

Good day pythonians,

I want to make a custom dictionary with two main features:

1. All keys are declared on creation
2. It is impossible to add new keys or modify current ones (values are still modifiable)

Right now code is this:

```
class pick(dict):
   """This will make delicious toffee when finished"""
   def __init__(self, *args):
       dict.__init__(self)
       for arg in args:
           self[arg] = None
```

Any help is much appreciated.

**upd:**

While solution is what I was looking for there is one problem:

dictionary calls the `__setitem__` to add the items on the initialization and not finding the keys it raises the error.

```
cupboard = pick('milk')  #raises error
```

**upd1:**

all solved, thank you very much.

Comment: Is #2 supposed to be "It is impossible to add new keys (existing ones are still modifiable)", "It is impossible to add new keys or modify existing ones", or "It is impossible to add new keys or modify current ones (values are still modifiable)"?

Comment: Ah! Silly me, I was a bit nervous writing here for the first time. It is (values are still modifiable)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Override the `__setitem__` method with your desired behavior, call `dict.__setitem__(self, key, value`) to modify the base dictionary without going through your base logic.

```
class ImmutableDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key not in self:
             raise KeyError("Immutable dict")
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

d = ImmutableDict(foo=1, bar=2)
d['foo'] = 3
print(d)
d['baz'] = 4 # Raises error
```

You'll also need to override `dict.update()` and `setdefault()` to avoid addition of keys. And possibly `dict.__delitem__()`, `dict.clear()`, `dict.pop()` and `dict.popitem()` to avoid removal of keys.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
class UniqueDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, name, value):
        if name not in self:
            raise KeyError("%s not present")
        dict.__setitem__(self, name, value)
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use delegation, rather than inheritance.
If you inherit, all the previous methods of the dict will be inherited, but they could behave as you don't expect, thus ruining the assumptions you have on the class, and doing it silently.

If you do delegation, you can fully control the methods you provide, and if you try to use your dict in a context requiring a method you have not implemented, you will get an exception, failing fast to the problem.

Comment: While you raise an interesting point, dict is a pretty transparent class and it's not hard to verify that you've covered all the possibilities for setting keys. So I would not recommend delegation.

Comment: yep. Got burned by inheritance. Now I am very careful ;)